# Apache redirect (.htaccess)

Tags: linux, apache, .htaccess

I'm trying to create two redirection using .htaccess.

like this:

```
"www.domain.com" redirect to www.domain.com/lp and
"www.domain.com/login" redirect to "www.domain.com/app"
```

This code works for second case but how to add the first case together?

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^login(.*)$ app/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this line:

```
RewriteRule ^$ lp
```

This will make /lp appear when / is visited, appearing as if it is the homepage. It sounds like that is what you want from looking at the existing one you have.